# Identifying the word picked by hugging face pipeline fill-mask

Tags: python, neural-network, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I want to use hugging face's fill-mask pipeline to guess a masked token and then extract just the guessed token as a word.  This code should do that:

```
!pip install -q transformers
model = pipeline('fill-mask')
outcome = model("Kubernetes is a container orchestration <mask>")[0]

#Prints: "Kubernetes is a container orchestration platform" 
print(outcome['sequence']) 

token = outcome['token'] 

#Prints: 1761
print(token)

#Prints: Ġplatform 
print(model.tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(token))
```

But I am finding that it gives me back `"Ġplatform"` instead of `"platform"` - does anyone know why this is or what can be going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply a peculiarity of the underlying model (see [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/pipelines.py#L1433) to check that this is `distilroberta-base`). 
Specifically, distilled models use the same tokenizer as their "teacher models" (in this case, RoBERTa). RoBERTa, in turn, has a tokenizer that is working strictly without any form of whitespaces, see also [this thread](https://github.com/openai/gpt-2/issues/80) on OpenAI's GPT-2 model, which is using the same tokenization strategy (see [here](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/roberta.html#robertatokenizer)).

Specifically, you can note that it is always the same unicode character `\u0120` that denotes the start of a new word. Comparatively, words that would consist of multiple subwords would have no such starting characters for the later subwords.

I.e., `complication` would be split into two fictional subwords `Ġcompli` `cation`.

Therefore, you can simply drop the `Ġ` if it appears in the word.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2021-08-14, the output of the pipeline contains all the information that you requested. Note that `token_str` may contain spaces.

```
from transformers import pipeline

unmasker = pipeline("fill-mask")

s="Excuse me sir, <mask> you speak English?"

unmasker(s,top_k=5)

[{'score': 0.9028477668762207,
  'sequence': 'Excuse me sir, do you speak English?',
  'token': 109,
  'token_str': ' do'},
 {'score': 0.05048234760761261,
  'sequence': 'Excuse me sir, did you speak English?',
  'token': 222,
  'token_str': ' did'},
 {'score': 0.015572326257824898,
  'sequence': 'Excuse me sir, can you speak English?',
  'token': 64,
  'token_str': ' can'},
 {'score': 0.007022920995950699,
  'sequence': 'Excuse me sir, Do you speak English?',
  'token': 1832,
  'token_str': ' Do'},
 {'score': 0.005521782673895359,
  'sequence': 'Excuse me sir, if you speak English?',
  'token': 114,
  'token_str': ' if'}]
```